# How to make a Fortran c_ptr null?

Tags: pointers, null, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a type with two pointers, one Fortran pointer and one C pointer:

```
type mytype
  procedure(whatever), pointer, nopass :: fortranPointer
  type(c_ptr) :: cPointer
end type
```

I can assign something to both pointers like:

```
type(mytype) :: instance
instance%fortranPointer => fPtrToSomething
instance%cPointer = c_loc(somethingElse)
```

When I want to initialize the pointers without assigning something, I can use `null()` or `nullify` for the Fortran pointer:

```
instance%fortranPointer => null()
```

But how can I initialize the `c_ptr` to null? `instance%cPointer = null()` is not working as `null()` is not allowed on the right hand side of an assignement. `c_loc(null())` is not allowed as `null()` is not a variable, which location can be obtained.

Is there something like a `c_null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out that there is a <del>intrinsic type</del> named constant `c_null_ptr` that can be used.

Comment: As a minor correction, `c_null_ptr` isn't an intrinsic type itself, but is a named constant of type `c_ptr` (so suitable for assignment and initialization for other variables of that type).

Comment: @francescalus Thanks. Wasn't aware of this internals.

Comment: Does one use pointer assignment or normal assignment to set a c_ptr to c_null_ptr?